# how to add app launcher icon to homescreen on android oreo(8.0)?

Tags: android, icons, shortcut, launcher

I am making an android app on Android 8.0.  I have read develop doc of shortcut changed before at [Using Static Shortcuts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html#static) 
but this doc has not method add launcher icon to home screen.

I have used method before 8.0.:

```
Intent i= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);  
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

Intent intent = new Intent();     
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, i);     
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, 
context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));       
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, 
Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, R.drawable.icon));
intent.setAction(com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT);
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

how to add app luncher icon to homescreen?
thanks.

Comment: Yes, facing the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on Android Developers

> The com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT broadcast no longer has any effect on your app, because it is now a private, implicit broadcast. Instead, you should create an app shortcut by using the requestPinShortcut() method from the ShortcutManager class.

Check out this link [Android 8.0 Behavior Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html)

Answer (score 0):

As we all know from android version 8.0 many behaviour changes. Try the following code in oreo to create a shortcut icon automatically at the time of install the application.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {


            Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);
            shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

            ShortcutInfoCompat shortcut = new ShortcutInfoCompat.Builder(getContext(), "shortcut")
                    .setShortLabel(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setIcon(IconCompat.createWithResource(getApplicationContext(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                    .setIntent(shortcutIntent)
                    .build();
            ShortcutManagerCompat.requestPinShortcut(getApplicationContext(), shortcut, null);
        }
```